# React router 4 with redux SPA boiler plate

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Where can I get a boilerplate for building SPA dashboard using react redux and react router 4 with nested routes?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options out there, I'm not sure which one will fit your needs best. These seems to have what you need:

[Universal React Router 4 Redux boilerplate with code splitting](https://github.com/jamesfiltness/universal-react-router-4-redux-boilerplate-with-code-splitting)

[React Cool Starter](https://github.com/wellyshen/react-cool-starter)